# Where do you set PEM file passphrase for Craft CMS Push Notification Plugin for an iOS app?

Tags: plugins, plugin-pushnotifications

Does anyone know where to set the passphrase for the PEM file that is configured in the Push Notification Plugin for Craft CMS?

I have created a new app and set the Certification Location to the PEM file location. I have tested on the server to confirm that the certificate and key files work. However, when I try to send a new alert -- I get the following error:

```
stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file
```

Which I'm sure is due to the fact that I haven't told it what the passphrase is. However, I can't find any documentation that explains where to put this configuration setting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Plugin Github Reference: https://github.com/boboldehampsink/pushnotifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research and testing, it looks like this plugin doesn't offer the option to set a passphrase for the PEM file. I had to create a new PEM file that doesn't require a passphrase in order to send a successful alert.